# C Prog: Avoiding data races in multithreaded read/write

Tags: c, multithreading, atomic, read-write

I have a library which provides reading and writing functionality to a global byte buffer. The following pseudo-code shows basically its contents:

```
#define LINESIZE 1024

char buffer[640 * LINESIZE];

void read(int x, int y, int len, char* value) {
    memcpy(value, &buffer[y*LINESIZE + x], len);
}

void write(int x, int y, int len, char* value) {
    memcpy(&buffer[y*LINESIZE + x], len);
}
```

Now, when I'm creating several (many) threads within my application, all those threads can either read or write to that buffer at any time.

What would be the best approach for reading and writing atomically w.r.t. related x,y,len sets ?

Using mutexes around both memcpy's would also block read/writes to the buffer with different x,y,len values.

I was rather thinking on using atomic operations - or the newer c11 atomics - but am not sure if this could be accomplished. I found the documentation very poor ...

Any help or other interesting approaches would be very appreciated.

Comment: You need to use reader-writer locks. Read locks only block writers, not other readers.

Comment: Making it granular to x/y/len might be overkill, especially if you have to deal with overlapping ranges.

Comment: @Barmar As far as I understand, the OP wants to give exclusive access to different parts of the same buffer to different threads in the same time.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm suggesting that it might be adequate if he just avoided locking out multiple readers. A compromise could be page granularity of locks.

Comment: Eugene is right. I want to have consistent entries at x,y,len when reading while others might write. And, usually x,y,len are predefined in another table, so that no overlap occurs.

Comment: If no overlap occurs, just add a *different* mutex to each range and use it for that range only. But I would just go to the dumb solution and use a single mutex, or what @Barmar suggested, unless it is proven to degrade the performance significantly.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look to tbb's `concurrent_vector`. It's very performant.

Comment: @Eugene I had that one already, a single mutex, but too slow, and prevents all other threads from reading/writing as well

Comment: @liliscent What is the concurrent_vector ? Can you link to it ?

Comment: @Mladen Part of intel's tbb library, but in C++. https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506203